# How to check if components already exists in viewContainerRef Angular

Tags: angular

Im adding components dynamically like this:

```
export class CustomersOverviewComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @ViewChild(PanelDirective) customerHost: PanelDirective;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private sidebarService: SidebarService) {

  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('init');

    this.sidebarService.currentAddPanel.subscribe(panel => {
      if (panel instanceof PanelItem) {
        this.loadcomponent(panel);
      }
    });
  }

  loadcomponent(panel: PanelItem): void {
    let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(panel.component);
    let viewContainerRef = this.customerHost.viewContainerRef;

    console.log('viewcontainer', viewContainerRef);
    console.log('element', viewContainerRef.element);

    let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

    (<IPanel>componentRef.instance).data = panel.data;
    (<IPanel>componentRef.instance).self = componentRef;
  }


}
```

But before adding a new component to the viewContainer i wanna loop though it and check if my component already exists or not. How can i do this?

I cant see any loop-able properties in viewContainerRef.

Comment: Am I mistaken or you are actually using Angular 5, not angularjs?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist sry i mean angular 5.

Comment: Don't worry, wrong tagging happens often on angular. I was just browsing angularjs questions and saw this one, noticed the error and though I should warn you.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you simply assign it locally?

```
loadcomponent(panel: PanelItem): void {
    let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(panel.component);
    let viewContainerRef = this.customerHost.viewContainerRef;

    if (!this.componentRef) {
        this.componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    }

    (<IPanel>this.componentRef.instance).data = panel.data;
    (<IPanel>this.componentRef.instance).self = this.componentRef;
```

}

Comment: Yeah maybe i can make a locally list then check if the component exists in my list. But there has to be another way to do this. You can create a component with "viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory)" why cant you check if your component is there or not. hmm

Comment: You can check how may views you have nested in your view container: `https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef`. Essentially, if (this.viewContainerRef.length === 0) { /* no component */ }

Comment: Yes i can check the length but not the type of view. I just want to add unique components to the view no duplicates.